# UI monitoring using net-SFTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, download, monitoring, net-sftp

I am developping an app and i need to download some files using sftp. I installed the gem net-sftp and its works fine. Using the monitoring process i've found on this page : http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/sftp/v2/api/, i can see the progress in my terminal. The thing is, i'ld like to let the user see what is going on during the process, showing a progress bar and maybe displaying a monitoring line in my user interface.

I have tried many things, but none of them work. When i enter the download loop, i can't modify any of my instance variables, so i can't save the monitoring data to display it with javascript. alter-filters doesn't work either.

I don't know how to store the information in the loop to use it in my UI. Any idea ?

Comment: It would be useful to have more info, maybe some code snippets so it's clear what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you have something like this going on...

```
1. client ----> 'do sftp tranfer' ----> server
2.                                      server ------> 'doing sftp'
3. client <---- 'done sftp' ----------- server
```

The short answer would be that you can't easily give progress to the client in this situation.

The longer answer would be that you have to open [some kind of stream](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) with the client to send progress.

```
1. client ----> 'do sftp tranfer' ----> server    
2.                                      server ------> 'doing sftp'
3. client <====> 'open stream'    <===> server
4. client <---- 'OK' -----------        server
```

The trick here would be communicating between the two processes on the server that are doing the stream and the sftp. s

Answer (score 0):

I'm about to jump into something similar, and I believe this will be my approach. I currently have the server accessing the location and downloading a file. While that's happening I will have the server check the file size of the file every ~ 5 seconds and report back the size.  If you grab the file size and report that back before the download starts then you'll be able to provide progress I would think.